# The maximum wavelength obtainable from a diffraction grating

Tags: optics, visible-light, diffraction, wavelength

I am trying to understand what exactly is meant by the following question:

What is the maximum wavelength that can be obtained with a given diffraction grating in (a) the first order (b) the second order. I know for order 1 the answer is $\lambda = d$ and for order 2 the answer is  $\lambda = d/2$ but I don't know the significance of the maximum wavelength. I can visualize the highest order diffraction number but I can't visualize the maximum wavelength.

Answer (score 1):

The grating equation is $n\lambda = d \sin \theta_{\rm n}$, so the n$^{\rm th}$ maximum occurs at angle $\theta_{\rm n}$.

The maximum possible value of $\theta_{\rm n}$ is $90^{\circ}$ so the maximum value of $\sin \theta_{\rm n}$ is one, $\Rightarrow n\lambda_{\rm max}=d$

Comment: thank you for your answer. I understand the nth maximums and I believe I now understand what was meant by the maximum wavelength that can be obtained. If I was creating a dispersion spectrum from white light and didn't wish to have any red or orange visible in the spectrum of the second order then, if possible, I would need to choose a diffraction grating such that 5.9X10-7 = d/2 where 590nm is the upper limit of the wavelength of yellow light in the spectrum. Is my thinking correct?